Elasticsearch to conditionally match all tags, categories and keywords
I am trying to build a music search function, using Elasticsearch 9.15.
I am currently using .NET client. I am happy to just get the idea how it would look like via DSL, so that I can replicate it for .NET.
Every piece of music can be like below json:
{
    "_source": {
        "duration": 258,
        "ratings": 67.8,
        "addedTime": "2024-09-25T16:22:53.0427917+10:00",
        "createdTime": "2024-09-25T16:22:53.0447736+10:00",
        "favorites": 9999,
        "votesUp": 7778,
        "votesDown": 4212,
        "languageId": 2,
        "tags": [
          {
            "tagId": 3,
            "languageId": 2,
            "name": "Australia"
          },
          {
            "tagId": 2,
            "languageId": 2,
            "name": "Good"
          }
        ],
        "categories": [
          {
            "categoryId": 1,
            "languageId": 2,
            "name": "Love"
          },
          {
            "categoryId": 3,
            "languageId": 2,
            "name": "Soft"
          }
        ],
        "singers": [
          {
            "singerId": 2,
            "fullName": "Bee Gees",
            "firstName": "Bee",
            "lastName": "Gees"
          }
        ],
        "qualities": [
          {
            "qualityId": 2,
            "resolution": 160
          },
          {
            "qualityId": 3,
            "resolution": 320
          },
          {
            "qualityId": 4,
            "resolution": 640
          }
        ],
        "id": "161d12b7-bcb6-40ab-9ea9-44683f15be45",
        "adamId": "xxx",
        "isrc": "xxx",
        "uniqueId": 1,
        "providerId": 1,
        "sourceKey": "BeeGees0001",
        "title": "Night Fever",
        "title_en": "Night Fever",
        "title_cn": "夜热",
        "title_de": "Nachtfieber",
        "title_ja": "ナイトフィーバー"
      }
    }

What I am trying to achieve is:

When there is no keyword specified, it would try to match the following criteria:
a). duration, which is in seconds, it should be within a range (minDuration parameter <= duration <= maxDuration parameter)
b). it should match all the tags, if tags parameter provided
c). it should match all the categories, if categories parameter provided
c). it should match all singers, if singers parameter provided
d). it should match all the sound qualities, if qualities parameter provided
then, it should sort by ratings desc, then by favorites desc, then by votesUp / (votesDown + votesUp) desc.

When there is keyword specified, it will match same criteria as above(no keyword), PLUS it will additionally match any of the titles (title, title_en, title_cn, title_de, title_ja), and any of singers by the full name, and any of tags by the name, and any of the categories by the name
a). It shoud do exact match on certain fields. For example, if the keyword is an ISRC. It must do exact match on the isrc field.


In a nutshell, the criteria are all conditional, depending on whether certain corresponding parameter is provided or not.
I am not sure how to "chain" all those conditions together.
Any thoughts?

Quick question, what is the mapping of tags, categories, singers and qualities?

@Val the mapping is based on xxxId respectively. For example, the client will pass the the ids of tags (matching by tagId),  ids of categories (matching by categoryId), ids of singers (matching by singerId), ids of qualities (matching by qualityId).

Thanks @unreldboy, my question was about the index mapping of the sample document you've shared, but that's ok as you got some nice answers :-)

@unruledboy can you share the output of
GET index-name/_mapping
Depending on the mapping, the query can change drastically.

Below is the base of what I will be working off of.
POST /songs/_search
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "must": [
        { "match": { "title": "your_search_term" }},
        { "match": { "artist": "your_artist_name" }}
      ],
      "filter": [
        { "range": { "duration": { "gte": 120, "lte": 300 }}},
        { "terms": { "tags": ["tag1", "tag2"] }},
        { "term": { "category": "your_category" }},
        { "term": { "sound_quality": "high" }},
        { "range": { "ratings": { "gte": 4 }}}
      ]
    }
  }
}

This approach uses a bool query to combine multiple conditions (must and filter). Using this combination allows for a precise and flexible search.
Are you able to provide more clear detail on exactly what you are trying to achieve so I can add on to this approach and provide an answer?

What I am trying to achieve is:

1.) If the user searches without entering anything into the search are you attempting to return a set list of songs based on some parameters?
2.) Are you attempting to simply provide the most relevant searches along with your standard list of songs below that?
From my current view point of the question, it seems that simply reworking your data (the way that it is entered and read out) could help you achieve this result. I just need some more clarification.
Using an Excel like tool to manage your content and get it into a position that you want it to be displayed could be a simple option.

Hi Zack, 1. if no filters / keywords provided, the system should still provide a list of records. I guess it should just return the TOP n based on the aforementioned sorts; 2. I believe the expectation is: if there is any filter/keyword provided, respect them, otherwise, return top rated/ranked/listened musics.

You can do a return top with duration desc or ascen query and that should work fine. If working in C# with .NET for the second part you can reuse the same query for if there were no keywords/filters provided and add in a try catch or an if else statement. If you need some assistance with that part of the code let me know.
